# How to rotate with shapes inside canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using canvas to load image using:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var context=canvas.getContext('2d');

context.scale(0.5,0.5);
canvas.setAttribute('width', tempImg.width*0.5);
canvas.setAttribute('height', tempImg.height*0.5);
context.drawImage(tempImg ,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

I am using other canvas to draw shape at run time using :

```
var annCanvas=document.getElementById('annCanvas');
var annContext=annCanvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth=4;
context.strokeRect(x,y,w,h);
context.stroke();
```

Both canvas's position is absolute, so they look like overlape on each other.but i want to rotate both canvas simultaneously (by angle value 90,180,270,0).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
context.rotate(90); // rotates 90 deg clockwise
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am aslo using context.rotate() for rotation. But i want to change height, width of canvas as image will get after using scaling(i.e. 0.5 in this case).

Comment: can you describe your goal in more details? why do you want to change the width and height of the canvas?

Comment: I am drawing shapes on image. And when i press rotate (either left or right) button then my whole canvas (canvas+annCanvas) should be rotate